# As bad as it sounds vs. As bad as all that sounds

Tags: idiomatic-language, relative-pronouns

> Artists who worked with lead complained of palseys, melancholy, coughing, enlarged retinas, and even blindness. But lead white's density, opacity, and warm tone were irresistable to artists like Vermeer, and later, the Impressionists. Its glow couldn't be matched, and the pigment continued to be widely used until it was banned in the 1970s. As bad as all that sounds, white's dangerous effects pale in comparison to another, more wide-spread pigment, green.

I often see 'as bad as it sounds'but not 'as bad as all that sounds'.

Is there any difference between them? Is the 'that' a relative pronoun which has 'all' as antecedent?

Answer (score 1):

"As bad as it sounds" doesn't need to follow what it refers to, but could be synonymous with "as bad as that sounds".

"As bad as that sounds" refers to something specific preceding the phrase. The addition of "all" simply emphasises that it is all that precedes that is being referred to.

Comment: Searching Google Books finds all these variants, as well as expressions like "as bad as it initially sounds", " as bad as it sometimes sounds", "as bad as he sounds", etc. You can modify it in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 1):

Here, *all that* emphasizes the author’s view that the problems were many, whereas *it* typically conveys essentially a single problem, or a group of problems considered in total.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom you're missing is *all that*: a group of referents taken as a collective, often emphasizing its size or complexity. Syntactically (and semantically, up to a point), it functions the same as *that*.

"As bad as X sounds" can use any noun for X, not just *it*. *It* often functions as a dummy pronoun here (its referent coming after), but demonstratives like *that* reference the immediate context just like they would normally: in this case, the previous several sentences collectively.